# Doubts regarding __init__ in python

Tags: python, initialization, arguments, init

I am recently learning classes of python through certain online courses so I am a totally novice of Python.

**Version [1]**

```
class Bubble:

    def __init__(self, pos, vel, colour):
        self.pos = list(FIRING_POSITION)
        self.vel = [0, 0]
        self.color = random.choice(COLOR_LIST)
```

**Version [2]**

```
class Bubble:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = list(FIRING_POSITION)
        self.vel = [0, 0]
        self.color = random.choice(COLOR_LIST)
```

My doubt is:

(1)
Comparing **Version [1]** and **Version [2]**, I am not sure when do I need to put the variable such as **pos**, **vel** and **colour** into **__init__(self)**  as **__init__(self, pos, vel, colour)**

(2)
What is the difference between these two versions?

Comment: In (1) you aren't using any of the parameters you are passing in, so they are pointless - you don't need to pass in parameters unless you need to use them for something (it's no different to any other function). Otherwise, they will both "work".

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the first example doesn't make much sense. `__init__` accepts arguments but doesn't do anything with them, and the values for the instance attributes are still hard-coded.

A more sensible example would be:

```
class Bubble:
    def __init__(self, pos, vel, color):
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = vel
        self.color = color
```

Now it makes sense to compare it to the second example you provided.

In the example above `Bubble` will accept 3 arguments and assign them to the instance attributes. Nothing is hard-coded and the calling code has control over the created instance's attributes (`Bubble(position_1, [1, 2], blue)` or `Bubble(position_2, [3, 3], yellow)` etc).

In the second example you provided the calling code has zero control over the values used to initialize the instance attributes since they are hard-coded in `__init__`'s code, and the way to create a `Bubble` object will be `Bubble()`.

A common approach is to accommodate both use cases by using arguments with default values (**just be careful not to use a mutable default argument**):

```
class Bubble:
    def __init__(self, pos=None, vel=None, color=None):
        if pos is None:
            self.pos = list(FIRING_POSITION)
        else:
            self.pos = pos
        if vel is None:
            self.vel = [0, 0]
        else:
            self.vel = vel
        if color is None:
            self.color = random.choice(COLOR_LIST)
        else:
            self.color = color
```

This could be written more concisely as

```
class Bubble:
    def __init__(self, pos=None, vel=None, color=None):
        self.pos = pos or list(FIRING_POSITION)
        self.vel = vel or [0, 0]
        self.color = color or random.choice(COLOR_LIST)
```

This way offers granular control, and `Bubble` can be called with any combination of arguments (0, 1 or any combination of 2 and 3 arguments).

Comment: Highly appreciated with such detailed information!! This is so useful for me!

Answer (score 0):

A small modification to your `Version[1]` code and it will be clearer.

**Version[1]**

```
class Bubble:
    def __init__(self, pos, vel, colour):
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = vel
        self.color = color
```

As you can tell now, we are passing parameters to the `init function`, which is being used to **assign** the values for each member in the class.

So your object is created, like:

```
bubbleObj = Bubble(1, [0,0], "red")
```

#driver value :

```
>>> bubbleObj.pos
=>  1
```

---

Whereas, in your `Version[2]` code, there is no such parameterisation possible. So in such case, the object is created like :

```
bubbleObj = Bubble()
```

---

This is similar to the C++ convention of `parameterised constructor` & `default constructor` respectively.

For further reading, look into the [Pydoc for Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

Answer (score 0):

#### Version 1

When you initialize this class with

```
Bubble1 = Bubble(pos, vel, colour) # args are required here
```

The init will succeed, but the values of pos, vel and color that you feed in as arguments will not be used, since you are creating class variables `self.pos, self.vel, self.color` without using the values received from the arguments.

If you do the class variable initialization like:

```
def __init__(self, pos, vel, colour):
    self.pos = pos
    self.vel = vel
    self.colour = colour
```

then this will be a more correct usage of the init function. What you are doing in version 1 is not using the arguments you are passing when you are creating the class object.

#### Version 2

Seems correct. You are assigning the class variables `self.pos, self.vel, self.color` inside the init method. Assuming you have correct access to the the value of `list(FIRING_POSITION)`, this function will work. And since you don't need any arguments to be assigned to the class vars, the class can be instantiated with:

```
Bubble2 = Bubble() #  no args in here
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of OOP will look more usable if you understand the basic idea behind designing class for particular problem. Let's give you an example:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, birthdate,email):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.birthdate = birthdate
        self.email = email
```

Here `Person` is a blueprint representing instances of it that you are going to create. And, all of the attributes `name`, `surname`, `birthdate`, `email` are specific to specific instance and based on these attributes we can define the state of any person. And, you might need to compute multiple instances of `Person` and compute other properties as per your requirement.

In your case,

```
class Bubble:

    def __init__(self, pos, vel, colour):
        pass
```

Though, you are passing `pos, vel, colour`, you are not defining attributes based on those parameters. That means, those passing values don't represent the `Bubble` in real scenario.

If you think `pos, vel, colour` are the properties/attributes which defines the `state` of your `class`, then you should define your class as:

```
class Bubble:

    def __init__(self, pos, vel, colour):
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = vel
        self.colour = colour
```